# How can I have git-checkout merge local modifications only if there's no conflict?

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-merge-conflict

When I use `git checkout -m`, it merges local modifications, which makes life easier when a file has changed between two commits but in a completely separate place from where my local modifications are. However, this becomes a messy merge conflict that has to be resolved when there is indeed a conflict, and I can't simply go back to the previous branch. I also don't want to have to use `git stash push` and `git stash pop` all the time, as that is cumbersome. Any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Use the stash:

```
git stash save
git checkout where-I-want-to-go
git stash pop
```

If it fails when running git stash pop (which is where the conflict might arise) you simply run back to where you were before, as if nothing had happened:

```
git checkout -f - # with single -.  yep, this takes you back, just like that
git stash pop # just as if you didn't move anywhere
```

Comment: I don't want to use `git stash push` and `git stash pop` every time I change commits with local changes, as I find that too cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

The alternative is to use [`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) in order to manage [multiple worktrees](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309) (one per branch)

That way, you don't have to checkout/switch branches, you go to a different folder, and you can import changes you want from one folder to the other if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider what I do overly cumbersome as well, but:

1. Attempt `git switch right-branch`.  If this works, great.  If not, proceed to...
2. Run `git commit -m temp-commit-do-not-use`.
3. Run `git switch right-branch`.
4. Run `git cherry-pick -n wrong-branch`.  Resolve conflicts if any.  Commit (replacing the "temp-commit-do-not-use" message of course).
5. Run `git switch wrong-branch` and `git reset --hard HEAD^` to remove the temporary do-not-use-this-commit commit.

Consider also using `git worktree` (as [VonC suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73383352/1256452)), since you can then open one window on `right-branch` and one on `wrong-branch` and swap back and forth just by moving your mouse.